# Sinch audio and video calling documentation or tutorial in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, documentation, sinch

**

Hi, I am trying sinch audio and video calling in swift, when I search I did not get any documentation and SDK for swift, can any one suggest me how to do this functionality in swift language. Thanks.

**

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can find the tutorial on sinch  here : 
https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/

They listed all the example  like verification and calling related stuff. Hope it helps you. You can use swift or iOS keyword to search for specific one.